# How to change the color of a specific record after update without affecting all records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access database where I'm making some new forms for users to visualize/make changes to certain product collections all at once. Previously they had to load each item up and then change them one by one so the goal of this is to allow them to simply view specific info they use often and then push changes across multiple items at once.
I have a temporary table populated by a search made by the user which will populate the table with all the items that make up the assembly. These child items are what need to be modified quantity wise. I'll attach an image of what the results are.
[image]

```vb
If Me.bbn_txt_QTY <> Me.bbn_txt_New_QTY Then
    Me.bbn_txt_New_QTY.BackColor = RGB(255, 242, 0)
Else
    Me.bbn_txt_New_QTY.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
```

Above is the current code, and what it's doing is changing all the records backcolor to yellow after I update a quantity whereas I'd like it only to change that specific records backcolor so users can easily see what changes they've made before submitting their changes.

I've also tried the below code:

```vb
If Me.bbn_txt_QTY <> Me.bbn_txt_New_QTY Then
    Me(bbn_txt_New_QTY.BackColor) = RGB(255, 242, 0)
Else
    Me(bbn_txt_New_QTY.BackColor) = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End If
```

All the data is stored in a temp table as mentioned above. Is there any simple way to tackle this? Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [Highlight data with conditional formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/highlight-data-with-conditional-formatting-7f7c0bd4-7c37-421d-adad-a260125c8129). The example shows how to change the text color, but it works for the background color as well.

Comment: This worked, thank you for the help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Conditional formatting.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Then, remove the Alternate Row Color. :)

[image: Alternate Row color]